# Cant find method in DataSource namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

So I have 2 files. One is DataSource where I get the data and the other is a ListPage in WindowsPhone where I want to bind the data...

I'm doing this in the exact same way as in the Windows Phone Hub template, just tweaking it for my needs..

The problem happens on my *ListPage.xaml.cs* where I need to refrence *GetApartmentsAsync()* method from *DataSource.cs* . I just don't understand why cant I find it. I inculded the namespaces and the method is public and it just doesnt find it...

[image]

Once more, I'm doing this parallely with the HUB template in Visual Studio and in their version the method can be normally called...

Now I will paste both code files and I hope you guys can help me somehow...

**Datasource.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Data.Json;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace ZimmerFrei.Data
```

{

```
public class ApartmentData
{
    public ApartmentData(String id, String name, String description, String capacity, String stars, String address, String email, String phone, String phone2, String rating, String lat, String lng, String price, String cover_photo, String owner_id, String type_id, String city_id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Capacity = capacity;
        this.Stars = stars;
        this.Address = address;
        this.Email = email;
        this.Phone = phone;
        this.Phone2 = phone2;
        this.Rating = rating;
        this.Lat = lat;
        this.Lng = lng;
        this.Price = price;
        this.Cover_photo = cover_photo;
        this.Owner_id = owner_id;
        this.Type_id = type_id;
        this.City_id = city_id;


    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string Capacity { get; private set; }
    public string Stars { get; private set; }
    public string Address { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string Phone { get; private set; }
    public string Phone2 { get; private set; }
    public string Rating { get; private set; }
    public string Lat { get; private set; }
    public string Lng { get; private set; }
    public string Price { get; private set; }
    public string Cover_photo { get; private set; }
    public string Owner_id { get; private set; }
    public string Type_id { get; private set; }
    public string City_id { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}



public sealed class DataSource
{
    private static DataSource _dataSource = new DataSource();

    private ObservableCollection<ApartmentData> _apartments = new ObservableCollection<ApartmentData>();

    public ObservableCollection<ApartmentData> Apartments
    {
        get { return this._apartments; }
    }

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<ApartmentData>> GetApartmentsAsync()
    {   
        await _dataSource.GetDataAsync();

        return _dataSource.Apartments;
    }

    public static async Task<ApartmentData> GetApartmentAsync(string id)
    {
        await _dataSource.GetDataAsync();
        var matches = _dataSource.Apartments.Where((apartment) => apartment.Id.Equals(id));
        if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
        return null;
    }



    private async Task GetDataAsync()
    {
        if (this._apartments.Count != 0)
            return;

        Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/Apartments.json");
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
        string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["apartments"].GetArray();

        foreach (JsonValue apartmentValue in jsonArray)
        {
            JsonObject apartmentObject = apartmentValue.GetObject();
            ApartmentData apartment = new ApartmentData(apartmentObject["Id"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Name"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Description"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Capacity"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Stars"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Address"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Email"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Phone"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Phone2"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Rating"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Lat"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Lng"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Price"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Cover_photo"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Owner_id"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["Type_id"].GetString(),
                                                        apartmentObject["City_id"].GetString());

            this.Apartments.Add(apartment);
        }
    }
}
```

}

**ListPage.xaml.cs**

```
    using ZimmerFrei_v0._1.Common;
using ZimmerFrei.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Graphics.Display;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;



namespace ZimmerFrei_v0._1
{

public sealed partial class ListPage : Page
{
    private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();
    private readonly ResourceLoader resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Resources");

    public ListPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;
    }


    public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
    {
        get { return this.navigationHelper; }
    }


    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
    {
        get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
    }


    private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        var apartmentData = await ApartmentData.GetApartmentsAsync();
        this.DefaultViewModel["apartments"] = apartmentData;

    }


    private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region NavigationHelper registration

    /// <summary>
    /// The methods provided in this section are simply used to allow
    /// NavigationHelper to respond to the page's navigation methods.
    /// <para>
    /// Page specific logic should be placed in event handlers for the  
    /// <see cref="NavigationHelper.LoadState"/>
    /// and <see cref="NavigationHelper.SaveState"/>.
    /// The navigation parameter is available in the LoadState method 
    /// in addition to page state preserved during an earlier session.
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Provides data for navigation methods and event
    /// handlers that cannot cancel the navigation request.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you try to call is implemented in DataSource not in AppartmentData. Just try

```
var apartmentData = await DataSource.GetApartmentsAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `ApartmentData` has no method called `GetApartmentsAsync`. That method exists on the sealed class `DataSource`.

Comment: incredible... Thank you man! I'm just starting this development and trying to figure all out, guess i replaced my clasess and just couldn't see my mistake...